# Gridbaglayout fixed position vertically

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I've two JPanels inside a JFrame but when one JPanel is bigger in height that other then it is being automatically aligned vertically center.I'm using GridBagLayout.Why is that though I set weighty=0? What should I do for aligning Panel1 to top whether Panel2 is bigger or smaller? Thanks.
[image: Two JPanel inside a JFrame]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridBagLayout` is honouring the preferred size of the components.

If you would like the components to have the same height, you can use the `fill` property of `GridBagConstraints` and set it to `GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL`, which will tell `GridBagLayout` to fill all the component within the given row so that they meet the height of the row (which should be the height of highest component in the row)

If you just wish to align the components (to the top), you should change the `anchor` property to `GridBagConstraints.NORTH`

See [How to use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more details

Comment: So me the code...(and you may need to set the anchor position for both components)

Comment: Thanks man . Its working. I checked the code agian.There was a silly mistake.Thanks alot.